# How to interrupt the talkback event

Tags: android, talkback

i have looking into Google-docs app, when an do explore-do-touch on some text, docs announces that line. When do bit fast, docs interrupts the previous talkback event and reads teh new line. I could see these in talkback logs :

Eg: SpeechController: Interrupted 548 with talkback_549

Could someone help me, how to achieve the similar behavior by interrupting the talkback events?

Comment: read the offical web page... http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html

Comment: @ExceptionLover  couldn't get much information how to interrupt the previous talkback event, could you please point me to the right place or provide sample code ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/accessibilityServices/talkback/src/com/google/android/marvin/talkback/TalkBackService.java?r=798

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but `TextToSpeech`'s `speak` has a parameter indicating how should the speech request be enqueued. There's a hidden constant value in the `TextToSpeech` class called `QUEUE_DESTROY` with integer value *2* that in theory should enable you to flush the whole speech queue (even Talkback).

Example:

```
tts.speak("I want to speak", 2, null, generateUtterance());
```

The important thing is the 2 in the previous example.